# Solspace User admin notification with custom user fields upon registration

Tags: solspace-user

Is there a way to send notifications upon user registration to an administrator with custom fields? EE sends a notification all right, but not with custom fields.
Thanks,
L.

Answer (score 1):

We ended up adding this line to mod.user.php:

`$swap = array_merge($_POST, $swap);`

Comment: I am also looking to display some custom fields in the registration notification. Could you please tell me exactly where you added the above line to mod.user.php? And is that the only change you made? Is it working without any issues? Thanks.
Susan